# Factor polynomial with irrational roots using quadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring, quadratics

If I want to factor the polynomial $x^2 + 3x + 1$, I thought I could use the quadratic formula to find that its roots are $\dfrac{-3\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$.  Then, since those are both negative values, take their positive values as factors, but WolframAlpha said my factorization is not equivalent (see below).
What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Your factorization is in the form $(x+\alpha)(x+\beta)$ when it should be $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$.  Note that the result should be zero when you plug in your roots.

Comment: Thanks, that evaluates to true but I'm confused: factoring $x^2 +2x + 1$ gives $(x+1)^2$, and the quadratic equation gives the root -1, meaning the opposite (positive) value $(x+1)$ is a factor.  Why is it different with my example?

Comment: In that example, the roots are -1 and -1 and the factorization is $(x-(-1))(x-(-1))=(x+1)^2$, so it is the same situation.

Comment: Maybe you are confused because the negative must distribute over the whole root.  So in your question, we have to negate both the integers and square roots in the numerators.

Comment: Okay i see - thank you!

Comment: recall that $$x = \frac{-3\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$$
means
$$x -\frac{-3\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}= 0$$

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

$$\left(x- \frac{-3+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\left(x- \frac{-3-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right).$$

Comment: Thanks, that evaluates to true but I'm confused: factoring $x^2+2x+1$ gives $(x+1)^2$, and the quadratic equation gives the root $-1$, meaning the opposite (positive) value $(x+1)$ is a factor. Why is it different with my example?

Comment: @Greg  Observe that $x - (-1) = x + 1$.  If the root is $$\frac{-3 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$$ the factor should be $$x - \frac{-3 + \sqrt{5}}{2} = x + \frac{3 - \sqrt{5}}{2}$$